# How to calculate the damped frequencies of a linear system?

Tags: vibrations, linear-systems

I am dealing with a vibration problem. The system is free to oscillate and its mass, stiffness and damping matrices are
$$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
    60 & 23.5 & 0\\
23.5 & 15.996 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3.507
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
  600000 & 117500 & 0\\
117500 & 117010.4 & -2000\\
0 & -2000 &  2000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
600 & 117.5 & 0\\
117.5 & 319.01 & -200\\
0 & -200 & 200
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The three matrices are not simultaneously diagonalisable, so the classical modal analysis gives superficial insight of the problem. The natural frequencies of the associate undamped system are
$$
\omega_n=
\begin{Bmatrix}
  143.078\\
 82.2742\\
 23.6099
  \end{Bmatrix}
$$
Through FFT I can see the frequency spectrum but I would like to have a more analytical approach. I know how to decouple equations of motion by complex modal analysis but I still don't understand ho to get the damped frequencies.

Comment: To be clear, what would the differential equation look like? Something like this: $M\ddot{\vec{x}}=-K\vec{x}-C\dot{\vec{x}}$?

Comment: @fibonatic yes exactly $[M]{\ddot{x}}+[C]{\dot{x}}+[K]{x}=0$, and it's a three DOF system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the differential equation as a system of first order differential equations,

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \textbf y = A\ \textbf y, \tag{1}
$$

where,

$$
\textbf y = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{x} \\ \dot{\vec{x}}
\end{bmatrix}, \tag{2}
$$

and

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & I\\
-M^{-1}K & -M^{-1}C
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{3}
$$

The [damped frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Under-damping_.280_.E2.89.A4_.CE.B6_.3C_1.29) of this system can be calculated from the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) of $A$.

Comment: this does not solve the problem, I'm afraid, the system is non proportionally damped so the eigenvalues of A are complex

Comment: @gravinozzo complex eigenvalues (which occur in conjugate pairs) imply underdamped eigenfrequencies. While entirely real eigenvalues imply overdamped (or critically damped if the eigenvalue has a multiplicity of two) .

Comment: ok but how do I graphically visualise them? The system is real, I need to see some real numbers to understand it better

Comment: @gravinozzo A pair of complex conjugate eigenvalues ($\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$) can be converted into the natural frequency and damping coefficient using: $\omega_n = \sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}$, $\zeta = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{-2\sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}$. It can be noted that only if the eigenvalues pair has a non-zero imaginary part, then the damping coefficient will be smaller than 1, so underdamped (and the damped frequency is just the imaginary part of the eigenvalues).

Comment: @gravinozzo "I'm afraid, the system is non proportionally damped so the eigenvalues of A are complex " - yes, that *is* the solution. Each complex eigenvalue contain information about the frequency  and its damping ratio. In general, the mode shapes are also complex - i.e. in each mode the degrees of freedom in the model move with different amplitudes *and different phases*, unlike an undamped structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, now I have a better understanding. Now I have the damped frequencies, two of them are less than their undamped counterpart, one of them is slightly more. I thought they $had$ to be less