# What is the meaning of each peak of the frequency spectrum?

Tags: frequency, degrees-of-freedom, linear-systems

I have a system with 3DOF. Its mass, stiffness and damping matrix are respectively:
$$
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
    60 & 23.5 & 0\\
23.5 & 15.996 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3.507
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
K=
\begin{bmatrix}
  600000 & 117500 & 0\\
117500 & 117010.4 & -2000\\
0 & -2000 &  2000
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
C=
\begin{bmatrix}
600 & 117.5 & 0\\
117.5 & 319.01 & -200\\
0 & -200 & 200
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The system is non proportionally damped and the natural frequencies of the associate undamped system are:
$$
\omega_n=
\begin{Bmatrix}
  143.078\\
 82.2742\\
 23.6099
  \end{Bmatrix}
$$
Through FFT I get these spectra, one per each DOF
[image]

So my questions are:
why the highest peaks are in that position and not near the natural frequencies that I found analytically? 
Also, what does it mean that the first and second graph, taken from completely different dataset, have such a similarity? 
And last, why that third DOF has a spectrum like that? I mean, what's the meaning of being so high near zero?

I'm perfectly aware of my lack of insight, that's why I ask you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with [transfer functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) or [the Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)?

The locations of those peaks can be calculated analytically using [my answer to your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/275345), by calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ from the equivalent system of linear first order differential equations. If the damping of a mode is below critical, then the corresponding two eigenvalues of that mode will be each others complex conjugate. From such an eigenvalues pair, denoted by $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, the natural frequency $\omega_n$ and damping coefficient $\zeta$ can be [calculated with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Linear_damping),

$$
\omega_n = \sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}, \tag{1}
$$

$$
\zeta = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{-2 \sqrt{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}}. \tag{2}
$$

Damping affects the frequency at which the system tends to oscillate. Its effects are different from the impulse response of the system (e.g. hitting it with a hammer) and at which frequency the strongest resonance occurs when continuously applying an input to the system. The system hit by a "hammer" will oscillate at,

$$
\omega_d = \omega_n \sqrt{1 - \zeta^2} = \frac{i}{2} \sqrt{(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)^2}, \tag{3}
$$

while the resonance will occur at,

$$
\omega_\text{peak} = \omega_n \sqrt{1 - 2\zeta^2} = \sqrt{-\frac{\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2}{2}}. \tag{4}
$$

Besides shifting the frequencies around a bit, the damping coefficient also determined how much each frequency will be visible, in a FFT plot for example (the higher the damping the lower the peak).

Normally the magnitude of an FFT from the position of a mass-spring-damper system is flat at very low frequencies. Near the natural frequency it would spike if the damping is less then one (the closer to zero the higher the spike) or gradually bend downwards if the damping is bigger than one (the higher the damping the slower/bigger the bend). After this the graph should go down with a constant slope. However in practice the measurement of the numerical values get overshadowed by noise, so the graph will flatten out again at this noise level. This explains the high values at low frequencies of the third plot, and you will see that it will flatten out if you would include lower frequencies in the plot (which can be done by using a longer measurement in time).

Comment: that is a wonderful answer. What is the explanation for different DOF having common peaks?

Comment: there is also another thing: when I calculate $\omega_{peak}$ one of them is purely imaginary, what is the physical meaning of this? just a change in phase in respect to $\omega_n$?

Comment: @gravinozzo The presence of a mode into multiple DOF can be found by looking at the eigenvectors of A. Namely the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of the mode will tell the contribution of that mode to each state and thus DOF.

Comment: @gravinozzo An imaginary $\omega_\text{peak}$ (and maybe also $\omega_d$) is because the damping coefficient is too high and the "spike" of the FFT will be already below the flat area at low frequencies, so there is no real resonance.

Comment: and what is a possible physical explanation (physical, not mathematical) for the third plot to be so high near zero?